# QLabel paintEvent() not triggered on update()

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

This question has been asked multiple times but none of them seemed to work for me. I am trying to draw multiple resizable/movable rectangles on a `QOpenGLWidget`. I have a class `Shape` which inherits from `QLabel` and i have overridden the `paintEvent` funtion.

```
//local
#include "Shape.h"

Shape::Shape(const QColor& color, uint width, const QRect& rect, QWidget* parent) :
       QLabel(parent),
       m_color(color),
       m_rectangle(rect),
       m_width(width)
{
       //One time update at creation
       update(); //Doesn't work
}


void Shape::draw(const QRect& rect)
{
   m_rectangle = rect;
   update();  //Doesn't work
}

/*virtual*/ void Shape::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* /*event*/)
{
    m_painter.begin(this);

    QPen pen(m_color);
    pen.setWidth(m_width);
    m_painter.setPen(pen);
    m_painter.drawRect(m_rectangle);

    m_painter.end();
}
```

I am creating a `Shape`object in the mousevents of class `GLWidget` and wish to see the rectangle being drawn in real time. It looks something like this:

```
/*virtual*/ void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    m_mousePressed = true;

    m_cursorPos = event->pos();

    QPoint pos(((double)(m_cursorPos.x())) / width()  * m_cols,
           ((double)(m_cursorPos.y())) / height() * m_rows);

    m_selection.setTopLeft(pos);
    m_selection.setBottomRight(pos);
    m_rectangle.reset(new Shape(Qt::yellow, 2, m_selection, this));
}


/*virtual*/ void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if(m_mousePressed && event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        m_selection.setBottomRight(event->pos());
        m_rectangle->draw(m_selection);
    }
}



/*virtual*/ void GLWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
       m_mousePressed = false;

       //Update one last time
       m_rectangle->draw(m_selection);
}
```

I have already tried to debug where i can see object being created but `update() or repaint()` not working. Am i missing something related to `QLabel` events?

Comment: Do you set the label's size anywhere?

Comment: i forgot to mention that tried `setMinimumSize(20,20)` in the constructor but to say no difference. Same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semi-transparent QWidget over QGLWidget: Strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604062/semi-transparent-qwidget-over-qglwidget-strange-results)